# Why Jackson wrap the string containing comma when rebuilding the configuration schema for building a record line for a CSV?

Tags: java, csv, jackson, export-to-csv

I'm getting data from a repository and put it into a CSV. For building a record line I use Jackson. My goal is to wrap a field (String type) with double quotes if that field value contains comma. So the output should look like this:

*some-uuid-value,some string without comma, SOMETHING, 123456, www.some.url, etc*
*some-uuid-value,"some string, but with comma", SOMETHING, 123456, www.some.url, etc*
*some-uuid-value,some string without comma, SOMETHING, 123456, www.some.url, etc*

I came up with this code:

```
private String toCsvString(EntityCsvRecord entity) {

        CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
        CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(EntityCsvRecord.class).withoutQuoteChar();

        if (entity.getName() == null) {
            entity.setName("");
        }

        if (entity.getName().contains(",")) {
            String columnName = "name";
            int nameColumnIndex = schema.column(columnName).getIndex();
            schema = mapper
                .configure(CsvGenerator.Feature.STRICT_CHECK_FOR_QUOTING, true)
                .schemaFor(EntityCsvRecord.class)
                .rebuild()
                .replaceColumn(nameColumnIndex, new CsvSchema.Column(nameColumnIndex, columnName))
                .build();
        }

        try {
            return mapper.writer(schema).writeValueAsString(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

However, I don't understand why it works like that, I couldn't find any descent clues within the documentation.

Could someone shed a light on this mystery?

Comment: I'm not using Jackson, but checking their documentation, I believe if you change first two lines to this: ` 
         CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper().configure(CsvGenerator.Feature.STRICT_CHECK_FOR_QUOTING, true);
        CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(EntityCsvRecord.class).withQuoteChar('\"'); ` then it should do what you need without any further checks on you part. You might not even need withQuoteChar call there.

Comment: yep, that works, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole trick is you enable [CsvGenerator.Feature.STRICT_CHECK_FOR_QUOTING](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-csv/javadoc/2.4.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/csv/CsvGenerator.Feature.html#STRICT_CHECK_FOR_QUOTING) feature. From documentation:

> Feature that determines how much work is done before determining that
>   a column value requires quoting: **when set as true, full check is made
>   to only use quoting when it is strictly necessary**; but when false, a
>   faster but more conservative check is made, and possibly quoting is
>   used for values that might not need it. Trade-offs is basically
>   between optimal/minimal quoting (true), and faster handling (false).
>   Faster check involves only checking first N characters of value, as
>   well as possible looser checks.
>
> Note, however, that regardless setting, all values that need to be quoted will be: it is just that
>   when set to false, other values may also be quoted (to avoid having to
>   do more expensive checks).
>
> Default value is false for "loose" (approximate, conservative)
>   checking.

All other configuration for schema and mapper you can remove and it will work in the same way. You can simplify it to below code:

```
class CsvEntityGenerator {

    private final CsvMapper mapper;
    private final CsvSchema schema;

    public CsvEntityGenerator(Class clazz) {
        mapper = new CsvMapper();
        mapper.enable(CsvGenerator.Feature.STRICT_CHECK_FOR_QUOTING);

        schema = mapper.schemaFor(clazz).withNullValue("");
    }

    public String toCsvString(Object entity) throws IOException {
        return mapper.writer(schema).writeValueAsString(entity);
    }
}
```

And simple usage:

```
CsvEntityGenerator gen = new CsvEntityGenerator(EntityCsvRecord.class);
System.out.print(gen.toCsvString(new EntityCsvRecord("Na,me")));
System.out.print(gen.toCsvString(new EntityCsvRecord(null)));
System.out.print(gen.toCsvString(new EntityCsvRecord("Name")));
```

prints:

```
8b572b1b-17c1-429d-887b-ec9af1c30d05,"Na,me",SOMETHING,123456,www.some.url
e86eacb1-d45e-4614-91bb-45f0d8840ea9,,SOMETHING,123456,www.some.url
e9627c32-6736-44a5-8eb2-7d153f86af20,Name,SOMETHING,123456,www.some.url
```

As you can see, we create `CsvMapper` and `CsvSchema` only once and reuse it when we want to serialise entities. It is much faster approach.

Comment: Reading the docs I was not sure what specifications or schemas the "full check" is based on. It's quite an obscure description for me. It seems something like this is taken under consideration http://edoceo.com/utilitas/csv-file-format

Thanks for the code instance, that really helped me a lot.

Comment: @AlexanderBerezkin, if you think my answer was helpful consider to accept it.